# A website for identifying the different phrases in the sentence

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if anyone knew of a website that allows you to paste in your sentence and the site will identify the individual phrases in that sentence. For example, I paste in the sentence and the site returns which part is a noun phrase, which part is a prepositional phrase etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you're describing is called ***parsing***.

There are lots of websites that parse sentences, you can google them. I'll just share two excellent ones:

- [Parse a sentence - Stanford](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/)
- [Parse a sentence](https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I know of for this is the [displaCy Dependency Visualizer](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy):

[image: Parsing "I was wondering if anyone knew."]